# Perform linear regression with sunspot dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to perform a linear regression using k-fold validation, in the sunspost dataset.
In this exercise I need to take the last 10 years as test and use the rest for tranning, further I should measure the model accuracy using RMSE.
Also, I need to test k-values from 1 to 24 in order to identify the better k value (lower RMSE)
However, Im obtaining very strange RMSE values for k (ranging from -6 to -1) while it should stay closer to 16 I think, considering that sunspot values are not normalized.
(PS: For the following script I've generated the day_count column imagining that the regression model does not accept date values.)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import reshape
import datetime
import random
import sys
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

df= pd.read_csv("sunspots2.csv", sep =";")


import pandas as pd
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_index()


# create train test partition
train = df['1979-01-31':'2009-12-31']
test  = df['2010-01-01':]
print('Train Dataset:',train.shape)
print('Test Dataset:',test.shape)

X_train = np.array(train[["day_count"]])
X_test = np.array(test[["day_count"]])

y_train = np.array(train[["Sunspot"]])
y_test = np.array(test[["Sunspot"]])

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
# Create model
linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Calculate our y hat (how our model performs against the test data held off)
y_hat_test = linreg.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
# See our Squared Mean Error score and Root Mean Squared Error:
test_mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_hat_test)
test_rmse = np.sqrt(test_mse)
print(test_rmse)
# See our Mean Absolute Error
test_mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_hat_test)
print(test_mae)

#See the RMSE values for each K (Rangin from 1 to 24)
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

lista_k = []
for i in list(range(27)):
    if i > 2:
        cv_4_results = cross_val_score(linreg, X_test, y_test, cv=i, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
        lista_k.append(cv_4_results)

for a in lista_k:
    print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (a.mean(), a.std() * 2))
```

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Finding the optimal K for K-fold cross validation is a bit of an odd task, so I'm not quire sure how you intend to do that.

The strange RMSE is probably because you've got scoring set to "neg_mean_squared_error", which is not the same as Root Mean Squared Error.

Comment: Hi, Ivo!In fact, sklearn presents the RMSE in negative values.. so I think that  is not the problem... since I repeated this processing for Iris dataset and it worked fine...

Comment: Calculate the "mean_squared_error" and use `np.sqrt()` afterwards to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the problem was that I've had prepare the date before, using the shift function in order to fit the 24 delays that I wanted, before perform the k-fold.